# phonegap how to decompress a file after download with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, utf-8, gzip, decode

i am using phonegap and JavaScript to downloading a file form a server but it comes in gziped, like:

```
X4�.��,�8�¸F�w(�b����b���)�E�����e����0���.�+QV�|�0�z�O?X�+V� �5 �ܼ�߄�>N�Q:3D�
��,�VB��d�z����ˏϙ9�?��s18�B���d<���ϵN�z�
```

any ideas how to decode this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gzip would be quite hard to implement in javascript, however, if you serve the file with 
the HTTP header "content-transfer-encoding: gzip" then it will be automatically decompressed by the client.